# node, geoip installation fail on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, geoip

When I install geoip (https://github.com/kuno/GeoIP)

```
sudo npm install geoip (-g)
```

I have this error back

```
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/root/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual
gyp ERR! command "node" "/root/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-    gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/test.com/node_modules/geoip
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.18
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Anyone has the same problem?
This happen remotely on Ubuntu 12.04. In local on OSX it works.

Comment: Can you please show the `npm-debug.log` file? and make sure that you have `make` installed.

Comment: ok, but.. emmm... I can't find this log file...

Comment: is it possible I didn't have this file?

Comment: Can you try `sudo npm install -g geoip`?

Comment: already tried, same error :(

Comment: Do you have `make` installed?

Comment: yes, i think. I did it with Xcode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37505/discussion-between-thefourtheye-and-codegirl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installation fails as it doesnt find `zlip.h` file. Please execute this command before executing `npm install geoip` command

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```